# How to Find the Inverse of the Function 13cos(12x)+1

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, inverse, pi

If the domain is between [0,pi/12], how would I get this answer?

So far, I have tried the following:

1) Switch 'x' with 'y', so, x=13cos(12y)+1.

2) Try to get 'y' by itself. Therefore, (x-1)/13=cos(12y).

3) This is where I get confused - how do you get rid of the cos around a variable? Multiply it by its inverse?

Does anyone know if the steps I have done so far are correct? And, if they are correct, how to complete the inverse equation? If not, how does one find the inverse of this function?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I am familiar with arccos. Would I arccos both sides? If so, I believe I would be left with (arccos((x-1)/13)/12=y).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: let $$y=13\cos(12x)+1$$ then we get
$$13\cos(12x)=y-1$$
$$\cos(12x)=\frac{y-1}{13}$$
$$12x=\arccos(\frac{y-1}{13})$$
$$x=\frac{1}{12}\arccos(\frac{y-1}{13})$$

Comment: OK, thank you for your help!